# Cloudcompare M3C2 vs C2M signed distance outputs (reference cloud problem!)

Tags: cad

I have two mode which using the [**cloud compare**](https://www.cloudcompare.org) for comparing those together, i used the ordinary distance compare method  ( **C2M** signed method) with this parameter as you can see here:

[image]

and for more details  i tried also the [**M3C2 method**](https://www.cloudcompare.org/doc/wiki/index.php?title=M3C2_(plugin)#Computing_M3C2_distances) by this parameters:

[image]

but there is difference in output as you can see:

[image]

So i think it comes form the M3c2 setting (which one is reference ,cloud #1 or cloud#2?!).

I have tried to give the reference stl file as cloud#1 and target to be compared as cloud#2 as at export part  as projection core points on cloud#2 i have tried projection core points on cloud#1 but i have get the same output and it project the colored compare results only on the reference cloud which is  Cloud#1 !.

i have tried to use cloud#2 as reference and the **M3C2 parameters** are this kind now:

[image]

and the colored output shown on the target stl mode as you can see here:

[image]
, but the difference in output is remained again! you can see here:

[image]

[image]
so what is the reason for difference and why it only show the cored output on reference could?!

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

answered [here](https://www.cloudcompare.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=17&t=4519&p=20598#p20598):

[image]

> So the two computation methods are definitely very different, and you
>   have to take good care when setting the M3C2 parameters indeed.
>
> Moreover M3C2 is not meant to compare meshes, but clouds. So you'd
>   better convert your mesh(es) to dense clouds first (with 'Edit -> Mesh
>   -> Sample points').
>
> Then M3C2 looks for the nearest neighbors along the input normals.
>   While the C2M distance just looks for the nearest points.
>
> And last, you should not focus on the maximum distance which might
>   only be set to a single point (= outlier) in the whole cloud. You'd
>   better use an absolute color scale (see
>   https://www.cloudcompare.org/doc/wiki/i ... es_Manager) and use it on
>   both clouds to see how and where the distances actually are different.
>   You could also compare the histograms.